# is it possible to create a hidden encrypted /home partition in linux

Tags: linux, partition, encryption, truecrypt

i know it's possible to encrypt your home partition (migration of home shown in the link)
http://sysphere.org/~anrxc/j/articles/ecryptfs/index.html

but later i found out that this is possible to install a hidden encrypted OS with a decoy OS installed side by side with it ( htp://www.truecrypt.org/docs/?s=hidden-operating-system ) . so i thought if that is possible can some one make a hidden encrypted /home partition so that he can use to different 2 pass-codes(passwords ) to enter into a hidden(i.e. also encrypted and) and just encrypted partition and depending on the passwords she/he enters the user will be logged in to a one of the respective /home partitions

please try to understand the Q? before answering .......

Answer (score 1):

i'm not so sure but it looks like you could use "ScramDisk 4 Linux" http://sd4l.sourceforge.net/

I never used it but, when i read the documentation it looks like it could work. but i think there is currently no implementation of a initramfs mount script or something like that.